# Http Response is not working

Tags: android, rest, web, parse-platform

I have a registration section in which the username and password are send to parse using rest service. That is working fine. In the login section I want to check whether the username and password are registered in the parse, so I'm taking http response but there is some error in my code. The response is not coming back for some reason.

My loginSuccesfull method is below:

```
private boolean loginSuccesfull() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        InputStream result = null;
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Login?where={"+"\"UserName\""+":"+"\"abc\""+"}"); 
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);
        if (response != null && response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            BufferedHttpEntity bufferedHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(response.getEntity());
            result = bufferedHttpEntity.getContent();
            return true;
        }else {
            // insert error handling
            return false;
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any error in logcat?

Comment: Is there anything in your url that would require you to use UrlEncode()?

Comment: Are you using the Parse library? If not I would suggest you do that. Their jar file provides you with a much nicer interface to interact with their APIs than manually making http requests.

Comment: @SiddharthVyas ya i m getting an error of Illegal Argument Exception in my querry but the querry is running in the parse

Comment: @lrb no url is fine it works for post well so i think it should work well for gethttp also

Comment: @FoamyGuy no i m not using the parse library..Please could you explain mee how to use it

Comment: @BirajZalavadia  username="abc" pswd="123"

Comment: @jyomin it is all covered in the parse docs. [Start here](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide) also look for the quick start guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parse server has an inbuilt Login Table we can use this table by adding username and password in that table and follow this to check whether the login is succesfull or not

```
ParseUser parseUser = new ParseUser();
                parseUser.logInInBackground( mEtUserName.getText().toString()
                        .trim()
                        ,mEtPswd.getText().toString(),new LogInCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseUser arg0, com.parse.ParseException arg1) {
                        if(arg1==null ){
                            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,CaptureActivity.class));
                        } 
                        else{
                            arg1.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"UserName or Password is Incorrect", 0).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

for that we have to first register the username and password in the parse using the following code

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(SERVICE_URI);
            request.addHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id",
                    "e7ynC0ZB1ts5EQVpghywywoUUCNafT4XZnoJO3j5");
            request.addHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key",
                    "w9iInpo0kPmzibzjyCkhyjO199tc5V0vqtafL2yW");
            request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            // Build JSON string
            JSONStringer TestApp = null;

            try {
                TestApp = new JSONStringer().object().key("username")
                        .value(mStrUname).key("password").value(mStrPswd).key("FullName").value(mStrFullName)
                        .endObject();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();                   
            }

            StringEntity entity = null;

            try {
                entity = new StringEntity(TestApp.toString());
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.d("****Parameter Input****", "Testing:" + TestApp);
            request.setEntity(entity);
            // Send request to WCF service
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = null;

            try {
                response = httpClient.execute(request);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.d("WebInvoke", "Saving: " + response.getStatusLine().toString());
            // Get the status of web service
            BufferedReader rd = null;
            try {
                rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        response.getEntity().getContent()));
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // print status in log
            String line = "";
            try {
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.d("****Status Line***", "Webservice: " + line);

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Thank guys for answering, I got it done using above.

Answer (score 1):

```
to make a successful HTTP response and handle all exception , use the following Code:




        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(httpParams, 10000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 30000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 30000);

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(BASE_URL);

        httpPost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(request.toString()
                .getBytes()));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        return EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("UnsupportedEncodingException >>>>>>> "
                + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("ClientProtocolException >>>>>>> "
                + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
        Log.e("CONN TIMEOUT", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        Log.e("SOCK TIMEOUT", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("IOException >>>>>>> " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("OTHER EXCEPTIONS", e.toString());
        System.out.println("Exception >>>>>>> " + e.getMessage());
    }
```